# JQuery Mobile 1.3.0 Collapsible Nested Lists Not Rendering Properly

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have a JQM page that is inserted dynamically into the DOM and must be regenerated every time, as the data may change. The first time the page is displayed, everything works as it should, but if the user returns to this page later, I have the following rendering problem. Here is the list closed:

[image: The collapsible list, closed]

Here is the list open on the second viewing of the screen:

[image]

I've tried various combinations of `$(id-selector).trigger('create')`, `.remove()`, and `.empty()`, but nothing so far makes the page the second time work like it does on the first.

For what it's worth, since this seems to be a problem with JQM for which I am seeking a workaround, here's the code that builds this list:

```
var url_base_key = resource.url + '_base';
html += '<div data-role="collapsible-set" data-inset="false" id="per-back-issues">';
if (window.per_info.back_issues.length > 0){
    html += '<br /><p><b>' + Label('label_back_issues') + '</b></p>';
    for (var i = 0; i < window.per_info.back_issues.length; i++){
        var group = window.per_info.back_issues[i];
        if (group.issues.length > 0){
            html += '<div data-role="collapsible" class="per_group" id="per-group-' + group.group + '"><h2 id="group-label-' + group.group + '">' + group.group + '</h2><ul data-role="listview">';
            for(var j = 0; j < group.issues.length; j++){
                var issue = group.issues[j];
                var url_base = window.orgbase_api[url_base_key];
                var url = url_base + issue.formats[0].file;
                var id = resource.orgbaseapi_url + '-' + issue.year + '-' + issue.month + '-lit_menu_item';
                var item = '<li class="per_item">' + GetPdfLink(resource.id, id, url, GetLongMonth('gregorian', issue.month)) + '</li>'
                html += item;
            }
            html += '</ul></div>';
        }
    }
}
html += '</div>';
```

This content is wrapped in a JQM page container

```
<div id="newsletter" data-role="page" data-theme="b" data-content-theme="b">
    <div data-role="header">
        <a href="#" data-rel="back" data-role="button" data-icon="back" data-mini="true" class="ui-btn-left" data-iconpos="notext" data-direction="reverse" data-transition="slide">Back</a>
        <h1>Newsletter</h1>
        <a href="#home" data-role="button" data-icon="home" data-mini="true" class="ui-btn-right" data-iconpos="notext" data-direction="reverse" data-transition="slide">Home</a>
    </div>
...
</div>
```

and added to the DOM every time with

```
var new_screen = $(html);
new_screen.appendTo($.mobile.pageContainer);
```

If I try to do a $('#newsletter').remove() before the appendTo(), the appendTo() doesn't work. I can't use an expand event to force the list to redraw itself because the event fires *before* the expansion happens.

Comment: Show us some code pls. You use `data-rel=back` or other methods?

Comment: I do have a button that uses rel-back. I included the code in my edit, but I'm hoping for a workaround to make JQM redraw the lists properly.

Comment: the above code is generated on which page display event? e.g. `pageinit`, `pagebeforeshow`..etc Do you use `$('.selector').collapsible();` afterwards?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the problem seems to be the use of `new_screen.appendTo($.mobile.pageContainer)` multiple times for the same id. I had tried to remove it using `$('#' + id).empty().remove()` if it already exists before the `appendTo()`, but I couldn't add it again (perhaps someone can help me understand why I can't do it this way). So I tried just updating the container if it already exists and that fixed the problem. I'd like to understand how adding the item multiple times led to the results I got.

```
if ($('#' + id).length > 0){
    var html = script + body;
    //update existing page container
    $(id).html(html);
} else {
    var html = '<div id="' + id + '" data-role="page" data-url="' + id
        + '" data-theme="' + theme + '" data-content-theme="' + theme + '" class="screen_section">'
        + script + body + '</div>';
    var new_screen = $(html);            
    //add new page container to DOM
    new_screen.appendTo($.mobile.pageContainer);
}
```